# Sklearn: How to pass different features to each target value in a MultiOutputRegressor?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, pipeline

Dear colleagues I have created an scikit learn pipeline to traing and tune different HistBoostRegressors.

```
from scipy.stats import loguniform
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.feature_selection import VarianceThreshold
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.model_selection import RandomizedSearchCV

class loguniform_int:
    """Integer valued version of the log-uniform distribution"""
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._distribution = loguniform(a, b)

    def rvs(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Random variable sample"""
        return self._distribution.rvs(*args, **kwargs).astype(int)


data_train, data_test, target_train, target_test = train_test_split(
    df.drop(columns=TARGETS), 
    df[target_dict], 
    random_state=42)

pipeline_hist_boost_mimo_inside = Pipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()),
                             ('variance_selector', VarianceThreshold(threshold=0.03)), 
                             ('estimator', MultiOutputRegressor(HistGradientBoostingRegressor(loss='poisson')))])


parameters = {
    'estimator__estimator__l2_regularization': loguniform(1e-6, 1e3),
    'estimator__estimator__learning_rate': loguniform(0.001, 10),
    'estimator__estimator__max_leaf_nodes': loguniform_int(2, 256),
    'estimator__estimator__max_leaf_nodes': loguniform_int(2, 256),
    'estimator__estimator__min_samples_leaf': loguniform_int(1, 100),
    'estimator__estimator__max_bins': loguniform_int(2, 255),
}

random_grid_inside = RandomizedSearchCV(estimator=pipeline_hist_boost_mimo_inside, param_distributions=parameters, random_state=0, n_iter=50,
                                       n_jobs=-1, refit=True, cv=3, verbose=True,
                                       pre_dispatch='2*n_jobs', 
                                       return_train_score=True)

results_inside_train = random_grid_inside.fit(data_train, target_train)
```

However now I would like to know if it would be possible to pass different feature names to the step pipeline_hist_boost_mimo_inside["estimator"].

I have noticed that in the documentation of the multi output regressor we have a parameter call feature_names:

> feature_names_in_ndarray of shape (n_features_in_,) Names of features
> seen during fit. Only defined if the underlying estimators expose such
> an attribute when fit.
>
> New in version 1.0.

I have also found some documentation in scikit learn column selector which has the argument:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.make_column_selector.html#sklearn.compose.make_column_selector

> patternstr, default=None Name of columns containing this regex pattern
> will be included. If None, column selection will not be selected based
> on pattern.

The problem is that this pattern will depend on the target that I am fitting.

Is there a way to do this elegantly?

EDIT: Example of the dataset:

```
feat1, feat2, feat3.... target1, target2, target3....

1      47     0.65         0        0.5     0.6
```

The multioutput regressor will fit an histogram regressor for every pair of (feat1, feat2, feat3 and targetn). In the example of the table below I will have a pipeline which estimator step will contain a list of 3 estimators as a have 3 targets.

The question is how to pass for instance feat1 and feat2 to target1 but pass feat1 and feat3 to target2.

Comment: can you explain in more detail what do you mean with `pass different feature names`? First impression is that you could use a transformer to drop features you don't want like [DropFeatures](https://feature-engine.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.x/selection/DropFeatures.html) or that you can create a custom transformer to select features you want.

Comment: Hi Miguel. Can the dropfeatures work according to different target names as my y_train contains 12 different targets?

Comment: so you are looking for a transformer that works like `column_selector` or `DropFeatures` but applied to a target variable? If your task is regression `HistGradientBoostingRegressor` why your target has only 12 different values?

Comment: Hi Miguel, my target has thousands of different values. What I mean is that I have 12 different targets and thats why I am using the multioutput regressor.

Comment: sorry for not fully understanding it yet, but you have a target variable matrix of dimension (n_samples, 12) and you want to select some of the 12 features, for example a matrix of lower dimension (m, 7), before you run the model with  `MultiOutputRegressor`? Can you give an example of your target variable?

Comment: Hi Miguel, not thats not correct. I have an X matrix of (n_samples, n_features) and y matrix of (n_samples, n_targets). I do not want to reduce n_features I want to ingest different features to different targets. I have added an example of the dataset shape

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is to modify `MultiOutputRegressor` so that it can filter specific columns to fit a model to individual target variables.

For example, I define a `MultiOutputRegressorTargetFilter` that accepts a `features_in` parameter which is a dictionary indicating which columns to use for each target `y` value

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.datasets import load_linnerud
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

X, y = load_linnerud(return_X_y=True)

# Pass a dictionary indicating which columns to use for each target variable value
features_in = {
    0: [0, 2], # Use columns 1 and 3 for y[0]
    1: [1, 2], # Use columns 2 and 3 for y[1]
    2: [0, 1, 2] # Use all columns for y[2]
}

clf = MultiOutputRegressorTargetFilter(Ridge(random_state=123), features_in=features_in).fit(X, y)
clf.predict(X[[0]])
```

**Code for `MultiOutputRegressorTargetFilter`**

```
from sklearn.multioutput import _MultiOutputEstimator
from sklearn.base import RegressorMixin, clone
from sklearn.utils.validation import _check_fit_params, has_fit_parameter, check_is_fitted
from sklearn.utils.fixes import delayed
from joblib import Parallel

import numpy as np

def _fit_estimator(estimator, X, y, sample_weight=None, **fit_params):
    estimator = clone(estimator)
    if sample_weight is not None:
        estimator.fit(X, y, sample_weight=sample_weight, **fit_params)
    else:
        estimator.fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    return estimator

class MultiOutputRegressorTargetFilter(RegressorMixin, _MultiOutputEstimator):
    """Multi target regression.
    This strategy consists of fitting one regressor per target. This is a
    simple strategy for extending regressors that do not natively support
    multi-target regression. This Estimator allows to select different columns
    to fit a model for each of the target values.
    .. versionadded:: 0.18
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    estimator : estimator object
        An estimator object implementing :term:`fit` and :term:`predict`.
        
    features_in : dict
        Dictionary with (key, value) pairs indicating which variables to use
        to fit model at target y.
        
    n_jobs : int or None, optional (default=None)
        The number of jobs to run in parallel.
        :meth:`fit`, :meth:`predict` and :meth:`partial_fit` (if supported
        by the passed estimator) will be parallelized for each target.
        When individual estimators are fast to train or predict,
        using ``n_jobs > 1`` can result in slower performance due
        to the parallelism overhead.
        ``None`` means `1` unless in a :obj:`joblib.parallel_backend` context.
        ``-1`` means using all available processes / threads.
        See :term:`Glossary <n_jobs>` for more details.
        .. versionchanged:: 0.20
            `n_jobs` default changed from `1` to `None`.
    
    Attributes
    ----------
    estimators_ : list of ``n_output`` estimators
        Estimators used for predictions.
    
    n_features_in_ : int
        Number of features seen during :term:`fit`. Only defined if the
        underlying `estimator` exposes such an attribute when fit.
        .. versionadded:: 0.24
    
    feature_names_in_ : ndarray of shape (`n_features_in_`,)
        Names of features seen during :term:`fit`. Only defined if the
        underlying estimators expose such an attribute when fit.
        .. versionadded:: 1.0
    
    See Also
    --------
    RegressorChain : A multi-label model that arranges regressions into a
        chain.
    MultiOutputClassifier : Classifies each output independently rather than
        chaining.
    
    Examples
    --------
    >>> import numpy as np
    >>> from sklearn.datasets import load_linnerud
    >>> from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputRegressor
    >>> from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge
    >>> X, y = load_linnerud(return_X_y=True)
    >>> clf = MultiOutputRegressor(Ridge(random_state=123)).fit(X, y)
    >>> clf.predict(X[[0]])
    array([[176..., 35..., 57...]])
    """
    
    def __init__(self, estimator, *, n_jobs=None, features_in=None):
        super().__init__(estimator, n_jobs=n_jobs)
        self.features_in = features_in
        
    def fit(self, X, y, sample_weight=None, **fit_params):
        """Fit the model to data, separately for each output variable.
        
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            The input data.
        
        y : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_outputs)
            Multi-output targets. An indicator matrix turns on multilabel
            estimation.
        
        sample_weight : array-like of shape (n_samples,), default=None
            Sample weights. If `None`, then samples are equally weighted.
            Only supported if the underlying regressor supports sample
            weights.
        
        **fit_params : dict of string -> object
            Parameters passed to the ``estimator.fit`` method of each step.
            .. versionadded:: 0.23
        
        Returns
        -------
        self : object
            Returns a fitted instance.
        """

        if not hasattr(self.estimator, "fit"):
            raise ValueError("The base estimator should implement a fit method")

        y = self._validate_data(X="no_validation", y=y, multi_output=True)

        if y.ndim == 1:
            raise ValueError(
                "y must have at least two dimensions for "
                "multi-output regression but has only one."
            )

        if sample_weight is not None and not has_fit_parameter(
            self.estimator, "sample_weight"
        ):
            raise ValueError("Underlying estimator does not support sample weights.")

        fit_params_validated = _check_fit_params(X, fit_params)

        self.estimators_ = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
            delayed(_fit_estimator)(
                self.estimator, X[:, self.features_in[i]], y[:, i], sample_weight, **fit_params_validated
            )
            for i in range(y.shape[1])
        )

        if hasattr(self.estimators_[0], "n_features_in_"):
            self.n_features_in_ = self.estimators_[0].n_features_in_
        if hasattr(self.estimators_[0], "feature_names_in_"):
            self.feature_names_in_ = self.estimators_[0].feature_names_in_

        return self
    
    def predict(self, X):
        """Predict multi-output variable using model for each target variable.
        Parameters
        ----------
        X : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_features)
            The input data.
        Returns
        -------
        y : {array-like, sparse matrix} of shape (n_samples, n_outputs)
            Multi-output targets predicted across multiple predictors.
            Note: Separate models are generated for each predictor.
        """
        check_is_fitted(self)
        if not hasattr(self.estimators_[0], "predict"):
            raise ValueError("The base estimator should implement a predict method")

        y = Parallel(n_jobs=self.n_jobs)(
            delayed(e.predict)(X[:, self.features_in[i]]) for i, e in enumerate(self.estimators_)
        )

        return np.asarray(y).T
```

Comment: @tfkLSTM does this answer helps your question?

Comment: Hi Miguel, this seems very close to what I wanted to accomplish. I will need a couple for days for testing but I will come back as soon as I can.